# Tracing through code

Tags: java, trace

I have a question about the result i get when i trace through the code. In the output one of answers is 75, now i understand how all the other answers come to be. I know that `int f = quip(b,10);'` calls on the method below called quip. In that method you see `int x = foo(a,w);` and this is where i get lost. Can anyone please explain this to me? 
-Thanks

```
public class tracing
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 int a = 4, b = 5, c = 23;

 int e = foo(c, a);
 int f = quip(b, 10);

 System.out.println(e + ", " + f);
 System.out.println(a + ", " + b);
}
 public static int foo(int x, int y)
 {
 y = x + y;

 System.out.println(x + ", " + y);

 return (x + y);
 }
 public static int quip(int w, int a)
 {
 int x = foo(a, w);

 System.out.println("quip: " + w + a);

 return x * 3;
 }
}
```

Output:

```
23, 27
10, 15
quip: 510
50, 75
4, 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int f = quip(b, 10); // b = 5
```

```
public static int quip(int w, int a) // w = 5, a = 10
{
    int x = foo(a, w);
```

```
public static int foo(int x, int y) // x = 10, y = 5
{
    y = x + y; // 10 + 5 = 15, after this line y = 15, x = 10

    System.out.println(x + ", " + y); // prints 10, 15

    return (x + y); // return 25
}
```

Back to `foo()`:

```
    int x = foo(a, w); // after this line x = 25, w = 5

    System.out.println("quip: " + w + a); // prints quip: 510

    return x * 3; // returns 25 * 3 = 75
}
```

Back to `main()`:

```
int f = quip(b, 10); // after this line f = 75, e = 50

System.out.println(e + ", " + f); // prints 50, 75
```

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot, now i understand.

Answer (score 0):

here calling the method with `int f = quip(b, 10);`value of

```
b=5 so w=5 and a=10
```

method:

```
public static int quip(int w, int a)
 {
 int x = foo(a, w);

 System.out.println("quip: " + w + a);

 return x * 3;
 }
```

at the line

```
System.out.println("quip: " + w + a);
```

output is `510` because `w` and `a` is being converted in to string so compiler is performing string concatenation operation.

the value of `x` is `25` so `25*3` is `75`